# Android MVP - CoundDown Timer in Quiz app

Tags: android, mvp, countdowntimer

I am currently developing Quiz application using **MVP** pattern in Android.
I am confused about whether Presenter will have reference of CountDownTimer class or View (Activity)?

CountDownTimer is responsible for showing/decrementing timer in quiz (which is part of **VIEW**), show options only after question is shown for few seconds (just like QuizUp app), finish current question when timer becomes **0**.

**Edit:**
Adding CountDownTimer reference in View can work well for showing question and options in specific intervals as well as showing/decrementing timer.

But I think Presenter should be responsible for finishing current question when timeout will occur and passing next question data to View.

This question may seem to be opinion based but I think this is more of architectural decision to make.

Comment: Could you show some code for your current setup?

Comment: @cricket_007 Currently its in very basic setup so no concrete code is there to show. Adding CountDownTimer in any of these (View or Presenter) but as I am trying MVP first time I am not sure which one is best practice.

Comment: The timer is meant to update the view, so to me, that says Presenter. However, I've never done MVP myself, either (at least not intentionally)

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? Putting the timer in the presenter and still match the MVP Pattern would require an implementation of the timer without using parts of the Android Framework. So no Handler or AsyncTask. It would need a more modular way of doing it like having a timer which holds a presenter, which gets called on significant time change to then tells the view to show the new time, which then would just set a string on a textview or something like that.

Comment: I'm doing something very similar to this. I have the timer in the view. The presenter calls the view's displayNextQuestion method (passing the question to the view in the method parameter) which starts the timer. If the timer reaches 0 the view calls the presenter's outOfTime method.

Comment: Personally think that anything that is Android specific should stay in View, the presenter should be able to test independently from the Android Sdk